# Able to submit answer after question is put on hold

Tags: bug, hidden-features

A few minutes ago, I submitted an answer on the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20196583/checking-for-win-connect-four-java. When the page refreshed, I saw that the question had already been put on hold at `2013-11-25 16:16:02Z`, while the answer was submitted at `2013-11-25 16:17:03Z`.

I am not sure why this happened. Is it because I had typed in the answer a long time before it was put on hold, and the draft's save time was before the hold time? (I was waiting for the user to reply to my comment before submitting the answer, but got tired of waiting and just hit submit.) Or is it because the version of the page I was on had not registered that the question was on hold?

Either way, I do not think that the answer should have been able to be posted, and I think it is a bug that it did.

Comment: There is a grace period for submitting AFAIK.

Comment: Oh, okay. I don't remember seeing anything about it in the FAQ, but I'll check again.

Comment: @juergend yeah, four hours grace period.

Comment: @jonhopkins you won't find it documented anywhere, it's one of the undocumented features in Stack Exchange. (there are quite a few of those)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, thanks for the information. I was pretty confused about that working. Four hours seems like a long time in my opinion though. And I apologize for the duplicate question. I searched for basically what my title is, but that seems to be too different from the others and they didn't show up. That was my bad.

Comment: Not your fault and no harm done - more dupes mean better chance for next person who search to find it. :)

Comment: Is it possible to tag this as [undocumented] ?

Comment: @user2987828, there doesn't seem to be an `[undocumented]` tag... Though there is `[hidden-features]`. Would that be an appropriate synonym?

Comment: [hidden-features] would be great, thank you; both duplicates messages do not have this tag, maybe it would be better to tag one of them.